# Quiverkey reference arrow is not being displayed

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, gis, matplotlib-basemap

The reference arrow is missing in my quiverkey and I can't figure out why.

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong? I originally wasn't using gridspec, but I needed to so that my figures scaled correctly. When I wasn't using gridspec, the reference arrow was showing, but now it no longer is. Why would gridspec cause me to lose the reference arrow for the quiverkey?

Matplotlib version : 1.4.3

Python version : 2.7.10

Note: the stick plot function taken from [here.](https://ocefpaf.github.io/python4oceanographers/blog/2014/09/15/stick_plot/)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.dates import date2num

def stick_plot(time, u, v, **kw):
    width = kw.pop('width', 0.002)
    headwidth = kw.pop('headwidth', 0)
    headlength = kw.pop('headlength', 0)
    headaxislength = kw.pop('headaxislength', 0)
    angles = kw.pop('angles', 'uv')
    ax = kw.pop('ax', None)


    if angles != 'uv':
        raise AssertionError("Stickplot angles must be 'uv' so that"
                         "if *U*==*V* the angle of the arrow on"
                         "the plot is 45 degrees CCW from the *x*-axis.")

    if not ax:
        fig, ax = plot.subplots()

    q = ax.quiver(date2num(time), [[0]*len(time)], u, v,
              angles='uv', width=width, headwidth=headwidth,
              headlength=headlength, headaxislength=headaxislength,
              **kw)

    ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.xaxis_date()
    return q



x = np.arange(100, 110, 0.1)
start = datetime.now()
time = [start + timedelta(days=n) for n in range(len(x))]
u, v = np.sin(x), np.cos(x)

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1,3, width_ratios = [5,1,3], height_ratios = [2,1])  
fig = plot.figure(figsize=(11,8))
ax1 = plot.subplot(gs[:, :-1])
ax2 = plot.subplot(gs[:, -1])

map1 = Basemap(ax = ax1)
map1.drawcoastlines()

q = stick_plot(time, u, v, ax = ax2)

ref = 1
qk = plot.quiverkey(q, 0.3, 0.85, ref,
              "%s N m$^{-2}$" % ref,
              labelpos='N', coordinates='axes')

_ = plot.xticks(rotation=30)

plot.show()
```

The picture:

[image: missing quiver key reference arrow]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem. Explicitly setting `linewidth` keyword in call to `quiver()` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

I guess that the conflict between the plot coordinate systems and quiverkey coordinate system has caused the problem. Try to output to figure file, such as:

```
plt.savefig("xxx.jpg")
```